# Fill Hourly Data Based on Constant Yearly Data

Tags: excel

I want to get values from a table that consist only year and value, and input these values into a table that consists of hourly datetimes for each year.

I've tried using nested if else statements to check if the datetime contains a specific date (sort of like a switch statement in C or dictionary in Python) however I have about 30 years worth of data and using if else statements gets hairy very quickly.

Example:

```
Input Data Table:
Year   Value
2018    100
2019    200
2020    300

Output Data Table:
 Datetime     Value
01/01/2018     100
02/01/2018     100
03/01/2018     100
...../2018     100
01/01/2019     200
02/01/2019     200
03/01/2019     200
...../2019     200
01/01/2020     300
02/01/2020     300
03/01/2020     300
...../2020     300
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it the annual average value you need?  The first value?  is the whole year always the same?

Comment: @ashleedawg assuming the whole year is always the same

Comment: This isn't [programming-related](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and I would therefore say it's probably a question better suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). -- or I would say you just need to make a pivot table...  But **if each "whole year' is the same**, that means you're trying to make a list of 30 numbers?  Manually **copy and pasting** would have taken less time than writing the question (or pivot tables or any other solution)

Comment: @ashleedawg That's fair enough, however the point you're missing is that copy and pasting every time the value for a year changes (which will be extremely often) will be troublesome.

Comment: alright - then VLookup will look it up for you.  I'll answer below

Comment: Will there always be a January 1st?

Comment: Where does datetime come into the above? I see only dates? If you are saying you want to add the appropriate values to the hourly date times by matching on year it would help to show a range of use cases from the actual data. Are the dates always of the format 01/01/2018  within the hourly date times in the table to fill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `VLOOKUP` function with the `DATE` function to find the first value that matches a given year like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(DATE(A1,1,1),$B$1:$C$10,2,FALSE)
```

where `A1` is a cell containing a numeric year like `2018`, and `B1:C10` is a range with the date on the left and the value to lookup next to it.  `2` means return the 2nd column.  `FALSE` mean *"Exact Match Only"*, or can be `TRUE` if you want an *approximate* match.

---

### More Information :

- Office.com : [**Getting Started with VLookUp**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)
- Office.com : [**Date function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using a regex to find the pattern dd/mm/yyyy and then extract the date from that. A dictionary is then used to return the value for that year.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PopulateValues()

    Dim inputDict As Object
    Set inputDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    inputDict.Add "2018", 100
    inputDict.Add "2019", 200
    inputDict.Add "2020", 300

    Dim valuesArr(), i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet '<== change to actual sheet name reference
        valuesArr() = .Range("A2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value '<== Based on datetime column; find last row; Assumes header row to skip
        For i = LBound(valuesArr, 1) To UBound(valuesArr, 1)
            valuesArr(i, 2) = inputDict(GetYear(valuesArr(i, 1)))
        Next i
        .Range("B2").Resize(UBound(valuesArr, 1), 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(valuesArr, 0, 2)
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetYear(ByVal inputString As String) As String

    Dim regex As Object, tempString As String
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9]{2}"
    End With

    If regex.test(inputString) Then
       GetYear = Right$(regex.Execute(inputString)(0), 4)
    Else
       GetYear = inputString
    End If

End Function
```

**Example test data:**

[image: Test data]